# Attempting to use Project Gutenberg in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, berkeley-db, bsddb, project-gutenberg

I was using the Project Gutenberg API (I'm new, forgive me if this isn't actually the right term) with Python 2 just fine. But I needed to start using Python 3 for other reasons.

I'm having a lot of difficulties getting Gutenberg to work with Python 3. I understand (according to this site: https://pypi.org/project/Gutenberg/) that I need to manually install BSD-DB, and I *think* that's the problem I'm running into.

```
brew install berkeley-db4
```

works just fine, but

```
pip install -r requirements-py3.pip
```

returns the error:

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements-py3.pip'
```

After research online, I also tried

```
BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --prefix berkeley-db) YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION=yes pip install bsddb3
```

which returns the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gb/z8bwwygn0y5gcknl24_7bfz40000gn/T/pip-build-_VUMDe/bsddb3/
```

I'm sorta overwhelmed by all the things that could be going on and starting to feel my lack of coding knowledge. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you clone the git repository of https://github.com/c-w/Gutenberg? Also can you provide the full output of the commands you run? I think you are mixing python2 and python3. Make sure to use the correct version of `pip` via the `pip3` command.